# For loop used to search an array, Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to search an array of objects for a specific value.
Is there a functionality in swift equivalent to `for(Distance d : distances)` in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to for-in loop?

```swift
let distances = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for distance in distances {
    if distance == something {
        // do something
        break
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let index = arr.firstIndex(of: 3)
```

the index will give the first index of the matching object.
There are other variations to it.
Check here for more details
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1848165-first

Update: Specific to your query

```
struct Test {
    let number: Int
}

let arr = [Test(number: 1),Test(number: 2),Test(number: 3),Test(number: 4),Test(number: 5)]
let index = arr.firstIndex(where: {$0.number == 4 })
```

the index will give the first index of the matching object.

Comment: How would I go about implementing this for an int inside an object as my array is of objects

Comment: @chad updated the answer with your specific question.